# Error al regresar a mi Activity después de tomar una fotografia con la camara de mi dispositivo

Tags: java, android

Bueno verán amigos, estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual consiste tomar 4 fotografías desde la cámara de mi dispositivo, el problema está cuando estoy tomando las fotografías y al momento de capturar alguna de ellas al regresar a mi activity me manda este error.

```
04-08 21:44:39.493 28084-28084/com.example.user.activofijo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.user.activofijo, PID: 28084
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.activofijo/com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4293)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
     at com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo.selectionspinner(AgregarActivo.java:1174)
     at com.example.user.activofijo.AgregarActivo.onCreate(AgregarActivo.java:151)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6018)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2370)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2480) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4293) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
04-08 21:44:39.493 840-3251/? E/ActivityManager: App crashed! Process: com.example.user.activofijo
```

por lo que me indica el error está en la parte del spinner

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
```

tengo 4 spinners dentro del activity donde cada uno de ellos carga datos recibidos desde un servidor solo pondré el código donde los declaro.

```
public class AgregarActivo extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
Spinner spinner_oficina;
Spinner spinner_departamento;
Spinner spinner_personal;
Spinner spinner_categoria;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agregar_activo);

 selectionspinner();

}

public void selectionspinner(){

    spinner_oficina = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_oficina);

    spinner_departamento = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_departamento);

    spinner_personal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_personal);

    spinner_categoria = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_categoria);


    spinner_oficina.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_oficinapost = arrayoficinas.get(pos).getIdOficina();
            String res1 = String.valueOf(id_oficinapost);
            tvO.setText(res1);

            spinnerdepartamento(res1);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner_departamento.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_departamento = arraydepartamentos.get(pos).getIdDepartamento();
            String res2 = String.valueOf(id_departamento);
            tvD.setText(res2);
            spinnerpersonal(res2);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner_personal.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Integer id_personalpost = arraypersonal.get(pos).getIdpersonal();
            String res3 = String.valueOf(id_personalpost);
            tvP.setText(res3);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    spinner_categoria.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            int id_categoriapost = arraycategorias.get(pos).getIdcategoria();
            String res4 = String.valueOf(id_categoriapost);
            tvC.setText(res4);

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

no entiendo por que me marca ese error, si alguien sabe se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 2):

El elemento `spinner_oficina` no existe en tu layout:`activity_agregar_activo.xml`, por esa razón cuando buscas la referencia se obtiene un valor nulo.

```
spinner_oficina = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_oficina);
```

Revisa que exista en tu layout.

Por esa razón marca el error `NullPointerException`,

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)'
>   on a null object reference

cuando invocas el método:

```
.setOnItemSelectedListener()
```